# Heroku Scheduler not running code like my Rails dev enviroment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, amazon-s3

I am trying to run a code snippet that takes a file from AWS S3 and saves it to a directory in my app. The code snippet is (`s3get.rb`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'aws-sdk'

#provide AWS credentials
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(
  region: 'us-east-1',
  access_key_id: 'my_key',
  secret_access_key: 'my_secret_key'
)

#download files from S3
s3.bucket('my_bucket').object('path/in/s3/test.csv').get(response_target: 'lib/assets/data/test.csv')
```

In my dev environment I can execute using:

`load '/path/to/my_app/lib/assets/ruby/s3get.rb'`

I pushed my app to Heroku and set up the `Scheduler Add-on` using:

`rails runner "lib/assets/ruby/s3get.rb" -a my_app`

I've played around with some of the paths and get various returns from the `heroku logs --ps scheduler` command like:

```
2015-05-18T23:49:21.585162+00:00 heroku[scheduler.1]: Process exited with status 0
2015-05-18T23:49:21.591063+00:00 heroku[scheduler.1]: State changed from up to complete
```

and

```
2015-05-18T02:31:50.543973+00:00 app[scheduler.7930]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.0.39/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/response_target.rb:46:in `initialize': No such file or directory - lib/assets/data/test.csv (Errno::ENOENT)
2015-05-18T02:31:50.543997+00:00 app[scheduler.7930]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.0.39/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/response_target.rb:26:in `block in add_event_listeners'
2015-05-18T02:31:50.543992+00:00 app[scheduler.7930]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.0.39/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/response_target.rb:46:in `new'
...
2015-05-18T02:31:50.544126+00:00 app[scheduler.7930]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `runner'
2015-05-18T02:31:50.544132+00:00 app[scheduler.7930]:   from /app/bin/rails:8:in `require'
2015-05-18T02:31:50.544133+00:00 app[scheduler.7930]:   from /app/bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2015-05-18T02:31:51.563689+00:00 heroku[scheduler.7930]: State changed from up to complete
2015-05-18T02:31:51.559159+00:00 heroku[scheduler.7930]: Process exited with status 1
```

I'm not sure if my `Scheduler` command is incorrect or if I am misunderstanding how the ephemeral file system on Heroku works. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my theory (feel free to shoot it down) -

Your job fetches the file with `lib/assets/data/test.csv` as target.

You probably do not have `lib/assets/data` folder created, and your process does not have permission to create it.

You need to create an empty folder `lib/assets/data` and add a `.gitkeep` file to ensure that the folder is not ignored in your git repository (assuming you are using git).

Comment: I thought that as well, so I added a dummy file in the 'data' folder and checked for its existence using 'heroku run bash'. I don't also need to add the '.gitkeep' file do I if I know it exists? Any other suggestions? Am I using the heroku scheduler command correctly?